# Is there an option on KustoExplorer so I can write my dates with UK format?

Tags: kql, kusto-explorer

Currently when I write dates in Kusto they are in USA format

```
//1st April 2022
let Date_USA = datetime(04-01-2022);
```

Is there an option in Kusto Explorer that would allow me to write dates in UK format instead?

```
//1st April 2022
let Date_UK = datetime(01-04-2022);
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid either.

The only place where you should ever use any date format other than ISO (yyyy-MM-dd) is customer facing applications.

ISO is the only format that is not open for interpretation by your software/SDK/OS and is not affected by any configuration settings.

`let Date = datetime(2022-04-01);`